# Macros like _GNU_SOURCE, what do they mean?

Tags: c, linux

Lot many times while referring to linux header files or man files, I see the following macros used..

Ex : `man mkstemp`

In this man page we can see that the below macros are featured.

```
_GNU_SOURCE
_BSD_SOURCE
_SVID_SOURCE
_XOPEN_SOURCE
_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
```

What am I supposed to understand to write a correct program if I am using these API's/Headers?

Comment: You should define more precisely what you mean by "correct program". Relative to which standards?

Answer (score 3):

Read [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) man page (and the [§1.3.4 Feature Test Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) chapter of GNU libc documentation).

You might compile your whole program with some special feature symbols. For instance, I often compile a program with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`. This means that I want all the extra GNU specific features provided on my system by GNU libc etc. You could instead compile with `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` if you want strict [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) 2001 compliance (and nothing more).

Alternatively, if all your `.c` files are just `#include`-ing only your own header, that header could start with `#define _GNU_SOURCE 1` followed by several system `#include` ....

The point is that a GNU/Linux system obey to *several* standards (with GNU providing its own standard), and you might choose which ones.

[GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) (which is the most common libc available on Linux, but you could use some other libc, like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) ....) provides a lot of functions, features and headers not available on other systems, e.g. [`<argp.h>`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) (header), [fopencookie](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Cookies.html#Streams-and-Cookies) (function), `%m` format control directive in `printf`  feature.

It is also relevant if you intend to code a program portable to other POSIX systems (e.g. to MacOSX). On MacOSX or AIX systems you don't have `getopt_long` since it is a GNU specific function.

Comment: Thanks. What about bionic libc. Currently when i use these API's (mkstemps) in android, i get implicit declaration warnig despite of including the header file(stdlib.h).

Comment: I don't know. Read bionic libc documentation. I heard it is not fully Posix compliant (border-line, i.e. it is usually is)